# При клике на дочерний элемент не распространить клик на родитель

Tags: html, css, jquery, checkbox, radiobutton

Есть макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот HTML

```
                                        <div class="table_row">
                                            <div class="table_cell">
                                                <div class="radio_2">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="gallery_radio" id="r_1" />
                                                    <label for="r_1">09/05/2019</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="table_cell">
                                                <p>200</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="table_cell">
                                                <p>10 %</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="table_cell">
                                                <p>20 +</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="table_cell">
                                                <p>5 +</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="table_cell">
                                                <p>56657</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="table_cell">
                                                <div class="star_checkbox">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="star_1" id="star_1">
                                                    <label for="star_1"></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

При клике на строку таблицы .table_row передается клик на зеленую радиокнопку radio_2. Также .radio_2 срабатывает при клике отдельно на него. Но чекбокс со звездочкой .star_checkbox должен срабатывать отдельно не передавая клик на строку таблицы. Как при клике на звездочку заблокировать клик на родитель .table_row ?

Comment: [`stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) ?

Comment: Если я правильно понял у Вас вопрос по JS.
В JS событие начинается от самого вложенного элемента и всплывет наверх.
Вот эта статья Вам поможет:
https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling